# Unable to list, update or build helm dependency charts due to permission errors

Tags: windows, kubernetes-helm

Sometimes I get below error:

```
PS C:\Users\user01> helm dependency list

walk.go:74: found symbolic link in path: C:\Users\user01\AppData\Local\History resolves to C:\Users\user01\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\History. Contents of linked file included and used

Error: open C:\Users\user01\AppData\Local\History: Access is denied.
```

some other times I get below error

```
helm dependency build --debug
Error: error reading AppData/Local/Comms/UnistoreDB/USS.jtx: open C:\Users\user01\AppData\Local\Comms\UnistoreDB\USS.jtx: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
helm.go:84: [debug] open C:\Users\user01\AppData\Local\Comms\UnistoreDB\USS.jtx: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
error reading AppData/Local/Comms/UnistoreDB/USS.jtx
helm.sh/helm/v3/pkg/chart/loader.LoadDir.func1
        helm.sh/helm/v3/pkg/chart/loader/directory.go:107
helm.sh/helm/v3/internal/sympath.symwalk
        helm.sh/helm/v3/internal/sympath/walk.go:84
helm.sh/helm/v3/internal/sympath.symwalk
        helm.sh/helm/v3/internal/sympath/walk.go:105
helm.sh/helm/v3/internal/sympath.symwalk
        helm.sh/helm/v3/internal/sympath/walk.go:105
helm.sh/helm/v3/internal/sympath.symwalk
        helm.sh/helm/v3/internal/sympath/walk.go:105
helm.sh/helm/v3/internal/sympath.symwalk
        helm.sh/helm/v3/internal/sympath/walk.go:105
helm.sh/helm/v3/internal/sympath.symwalk
        helm.sh/helm/v3/internal/sympath/walk.go:105
helm.sh/helm/v3/internal/sympath.Walk
        helm.sh/helm/v3/internal/sympath/walk.go:42
helm.sh/helm/v3/pkg/chart/loader.LoadDir
        helm.sh/helm/v3/pkg/chart/loader/directory.go:115
helm.sh/helm/v3/pkg/downloader.(*Manager).loadChartDir
        helm.sh/helm/v3/pkg/downloader/manager.go:228
helm.sh/helm/v3/pkg/downloader.(*Manager).Build
        helm.sh/helm/v3/pkg/downloader/manager.go:87
main.newDependencyBuildCmd.func1
        helm.sh/helm/v3/cmd/helm/dependency_build.go:71
github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).execute
        github.com/spf13/cobra@v1.3.0/command.go:856
github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).ExecuteC
        github.com/spf13/cobra@v1.3.0/command.go:974
github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).Execute
        github.com/spf13/cobra@v1.3.0/command.go:902
main.main
        helm.sh/helm/v3/cmd/helm/helm.go:83
runtime.main
        runtime/proc.go:255
runtime.goexit
        runtime/asm_amd64.s:1581
PS C:\Users\user01>


PS C:\Users\user01> helm version --short
v3.12.0+gc9f554d
PS C:\Users\user01>
```

Getting one more error now:

```
PS C:\Users\user01> helm dependency list
Error: error reading AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data/Default/Cache/Cache_Data/data_0: open C:\Users\user01\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Cache\Cache_Data\data_0: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
```

Has anyone faced this issue ?I'm not able to install any helm charts with dependency helm charts.

I tried to delete those open files using right click delete and delete forcefully from Powershell but cannot because the file is handled by another process (svchost.exe).

Also tried rebooting the machines many times which didn't work.

I tried multiple helm versions as well didn't work.

I tried run helm list, build and update all three commands are failing.

Comment: Hi, by any chance were you able to solve it? I'm facing the same issue and I don't seem to find a solution so far. Cheers.

Comment: Usage: I missed CHART name while running, please specify the CHART name and it should work.
  helm dependency build CHART [flags]

Answer (score 1):

Usage: I missed CHART name while running, please specify the CHART name and it should work.
helm dependency build CHART [flags]